# How to remove HTML tags using VBscript?

Tags: vbscript

How to remove HTML tags from a string using VBscript? Whether there is any function available?

Comment: There's no explicit function available, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Whether there is any code for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the string only contains fairly basic HTML and you're sure that the text will never contain `<` or `>` you might just be able loop through the text and use `InStr` to find all the `<` and `>` and the use `Mid` to keep all the text that's not between those.

Otherwise, this CodeProject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/removehtml.aspx) contains a function that's supposed to do it in better way in the section named **Fourth Option - Another VBScript attempt**. However, the article doesn't mention any license information which might be an issue for you.